# Skip/Ignore boot errors for vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

Hi Guys I have a situation where I don't want use vagrant user or any other user for ssh. Whenever I do vagrant up the VM's boots and I get the below error for ssh. Its because of timeout as it is unable to find vagrant user. By default when we do vagrant up the vagrants checks for vm to boot and it does the same by sshing. Is there is way where I can ignore this bootstrap error or skip the ssh step? I did an extensive search and unable to find any documentation regarding the same. The reason I need this is because I have multiple VM which needs to be started one by one. I need to skip this error or ignore the below error so that all the VM's are started.

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant
>   had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are
>   usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

Comment: `The reason I need this is because I have multiple VM which needs to be started one by one` how does this even matter?  starting vm is one thing, ssh to guest another. why you ssh there if you do not need it?

Comment: According to _vagrant_ tag description, general questions about it are considered OT here and should be rather asked in _Superuser_ site.

Comment: Because, whenever we run vagrant up by default vagrant checks if the VM is booted by sshing.

Comment: What about using a provisioner in the Vagrantfile to stop the ssh service?

Comment: It won't reach provision state unless the boot stage is finished.